# When i click on back button of the browser i still get back to back page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have used `Session.Abandon();` `Session.Clear();` on Logout Button and redirected to Login page.
BUT
When i click on back button of the browser i still get back to back page.

Comment: Could you please add some tags and tell us something about your environment?

Comment: Yes i have added tag C#

Answer (score 1):

Because it is fetching page from cache, you may want to disable cache for those respective page.

Some people asks for disabling back button, it is not possible to disable back button. Alternatives are:

- Prevent Caching those page
- Prevent User from going back once user logs out of application.

For second case, check out the below code and put it in your login page.

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
function changeHashOnLoad() {
 window.location.href += "#";
 setTimeout("changeHashAgain()", "50"); 
}

function changeHashAgain() {
 window.location.href += "1";
}

var storedHash = window.location.hash;
window.setInterval(function () {
if (window.location.hash != storedHash) {
     window.location.hash = storedHash;
}
}, 50);


 </script>
```

and Call it like below:

```
<body onload="changeHashOnLoad(); ">
 //---Rest of your code
```

It will work in all the browser.

Source: SO (don't have link to the original thread)

Answer (score 0):

You can use use like follows

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
Session.Abandon();

 // clear authentication cookie
 HttpCookie cookie1 = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, "");
 cookie1.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
 Response.Cookies.Add(cookie1);

// clear session cookie (not necessary for your current problem but i would recommend you do it anyway)

HttpCookie cookie2 = new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", "");
cookie2.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie2);

FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
```