# Stop redirect page on back button click

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

I'm trying to remove history for a particular site. When I'm logout the page and then press back button, the page move in previous page but I want when any user logout and then press back button it will be on same page that is login page not go in previous page. I'm trying all method like session abandon, cache remove but my problem not solved. We can also use JavaScript.

```
protected void btnLogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove("");
    HttpContext.Current.Session.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
    Response.Redirect("../Login.aspx");
}
```

Comment: What is the code in pageload event of the 'previous' page? Do you want to erase the history or only end the session on 'logout'?

Comment: this is previous page and on logout button it redirect to login page..

Comment: Still, my question remains same.

Comment: Check now and if answer was correct, then mark as answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using javascript:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    //Logout clears all visited pages for Back Button
    function noBack() { window.history.forward(); }
    noBack();
    window.onload = noBack;
    window.onpageshow = function (evt) { if (evt.persisted) noBack(); }
    window.onunload = function () { void (0); }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If page is served using cache then do the below things to set the proper http headers

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1));
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

Answer (score 0):

You've two options:

Prevent page from being cached
Prevent user from going back to previous page after he logs out using JavaScript.

I would suggest the first one but if it doesn't work for you, go for the second option as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717424/when-i-click-on-back-button-of-the-browser-i-still-get-back-to-back-page/15717530#15717530)

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, it looks like you are handling people logged on by session variables. If that is the case, then in the master page or a base page couldn't you check to make sure that person is logged on by checking the presence of a certain session variable? If they are logged on, continue as normal, if not then you could redirect them back to the logon page (or default) to make them log on?

Answer (score 0):

In the code behind add the below code

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);
        string strDisAbleBackButton;
        strDisAbleBackButton = "<script language=\"javascript\">\n";
        strDisAbleBackButton += "window.history.forward(1);\n";
        strDisAbleBackButton += "\n</script>";
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page.GetType(), "clientScript", strDisAbleBackButton);
    }
    protected void Page_Init(object Sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1));
        Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
    }
```

Hope the above code will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use react and then, useEffect to have constant looping default such as /page=0 or /login added to the path say /accounts/login/login so when they click back it will just re-route to the same page as it can't go back, because its an infinite loop.

Answer (score -1):

This question has been asked several times in stack overflow.A simple search would get you a solution.
After logout you have to disable back button.for that you have to use

```
Page.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
```

Removing cache itself will stop navigating backwards.

Comment: I know that but i am not satify with any answer so please help me according to that code

Comment: Yes my logout button on master page and it is redirect on login page o logout button click

Comment: thanks it work only when one time click on back button when two time continuously click on back button it goes on previous save page

Comment: If it solved your issues then give upvotes and mark as answer.

Comment: i give you up vote for that my question not solved completely. please read my previous comment

Comment: This is not appropriate answer